# Trying to pass a table-valued parameter with 20 column(s) where the corresponding user-defined table type requires 21 column(s)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I get this error:

> Additional information: Trying to pass a table-valued parameter with 20 column(s) where the corresponding user-defined table type requires 21 column(s).

Because I'm trying to read an Excel file with 20 columns and create a datatable, then pass the data from the datatable to SQL Server. But the table in SQL Server has 21 columns because the `ID` is an auto-increment column.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can't you pass dummy values to the UDT and then just not use them when you do the insert to the db table?

Comment: Yes, either not include the auto-increment column in your usre defined table type, or populate it with values when reading the excel data.

Comment: You need to provide more information, some code would be useful. SQL supports the DEFAULT keyword for values that are auto-incremented or you might skip that column name in your insert statement

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.